# How to test if a string contains any digits in C++

Tags: c++, string

I want to know if a string has any digits, or if there are no digits.  Is there a function that easily does this?

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps the following:

```
if (std::string::npos != s.find_first_of("0123456789")) {
  std::cout << "digit(s)found!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This requires O(10*n) steps. A [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9642381/145173) with `find_if` or `find_any` is faster, requiring only O(n) steps.

Answer (score 7):

```
boost::regex re("[0-9]");
const std::string src = "test 123 test";
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what; 
bool search_result = 
   boost::regex_search(src.begin(), src.end(), what, re, boost::match_default);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

if (std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), (int(*)(int))std::isdigit) != s.end())
{
  // contains digit
}
```

Comment: It's weird, in VC++ the cast is not necessary, and in GNU it's not necessary either if you remove the `std::` part before `isdigit`. Anybody knows why this is so?

Comment: @Manuel: `<cctype>` includes the Unix/C `<ctype.h>` and imports its contents with `using`, on Mac OS X at least. §17.4.1.2/4 would seem to say that this methodology is illegal, and `<cctype>` shouldn't define `::isdigit`. Could it be intentional nonconformance?

Comment: @Potatoswatter - VSC++ 2008 does the same thing, not only for `ctype` but for the entire C std library. Anyway this does not answer why the version with `std::` in front requires a cast.

Comment: It's because the `isdigit` from `<cctype>` is a function with type `int(*)(int)` already. `std::isdigit` is a template, so without the cast it's ambiguous. It's in `<locale>`, but I expect you're picking it up from `<string>`. So once `<cctype>` has done its thing, which we're not sure is conforming but is certainly common, `::isdigit` is unambiguously a particular function, whereas `std::isdigit` is overloaded as the function from `<cctype>` plus the template from `<locale>`. None of the template's instantiations has return type `int`, but without the cast they can't be ruled out.

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for the great explanation, I had forgotten about `locale`

Answer (score 3):

`find_first_of` is probably your best bet, but I've been playing around with iostream facets so here's an alternative:

```
if ( use_facet< ctype<char> >( locale() ).scan_is( ctype<char>::digit,
      str.data(), str.data() + str.size() ) != str.data + str.size() )
```

Change `string` to `wstring` and `char` to `wchar` and you might theoretically have a chance at handling those weird fixed-width digits used in some Asian scripts.

Comment: kewl, an upvote. Unfortunately, I tried this later on (in Mac OS X, which has somewhat lackluster locales) and fullwidth digits turned out to be non-numeric.

Answer (score 2):

given std::String s;

```
if( s.find_first_of("0123456789")!=std::string::npos )
//digits
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing standard for the purpose, but it's not difficult to make one:

```
template <typename CharT>
bool has_digits(std::basic_string<CharT> &input)
{
    typedef typename std::basic_string<CharT>::iterator IteratorType;
    IteratorType it =
        std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
                     std::tr1::bind(std::isdigit<CharT>,
                                    std::tr1::placeholders::_1,
                                    std::locale()));
    return it != input.end();
}
```

And you can use it like so:

```
std::string str("abcde123xyz");
printf("Has digits: %s\n", has_digits(str) ? "yes" : "no");
```

Edit:

Or even *better* version (for it can work with any container and with both const and non-const containers):

```
template <typename InputIterator>
bool has_digits(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    typedef typename InputIterator::value_type CharT;
    InputIterator it =
        std::find_if(first, last,
                     std::tr1::bind(std::isdigit<CharT>,
                                    std::tr1::placeholders::_1,
                                    std::locale()));
    return it != last;
}
```

And this one you can use like:

```
const std::string str("abcde123xyz");
printf("Has digits: %s\n", has_digits(str.begin(), str.end()) ? "yes" : "no");
```